# apt-get purge <packages> works fine, aptitude still has <packages> marked as installed and reinstalls them

Tags: kernel, apt, disk-usage, dpkg, aptitude

I've created a [Rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dekernel) to help with removing old kernels that have built up over years and are eating disk space. (My laptop had 19 kernels on it alone, and on a small SSD...)

I want to use apt-get or dpkg as the uninstaller since some people will not have aptitude installed and I do not want users of the gem to have to install anything.

The problem comes when *some* users do use `aptitude` for other things. Scenario:

1. User uses my gem which successfully `apt-get purge`'s the kernel packages.
2. User starts `aptitude` in interactive mode for any reason,
3. User presses the 'g' key (Download/Install/Remove Pkgs) immediately without marking any changes, -->
4. `aptitude` re-downloads and re-installs the packages that `apt-get` had purged.

Currently, the gem uses `apt-get purge <packages>` to purge the kernel packages. ([Seen here](https://github.com/snarlysodboxer/deKernel/blob/master/lib/dekernel/cernel.rb#L20).)
I also tried with `dpkg --purge <packages>`, but the result is the same, aptitude still wants to reinstall them.

I've read through the entire `aptitude` manual and googled many things, no dice.

*Maybe* I could programmatically manage `aptitude`'s marked/unmarked packages list if I could find where it is (although I'd prefer a cleaner solution.) I assume it's not `/var/lib/dpkg/status` or else there would be no disparity?

dpkg-query shows the package `status` as `Not` and the `desired` state as `Unknown`.

```
deKernel$ dpkg-query -l linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                                    Description
+++-==========================================-==========================================-====================================================================================================
un  linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic               <none>                                     (no description available)
deKernel$
```

It's possible to go into aptitude and manually un-mark those kernel packages and the problem disappears, however this is obviously quite impractical.

Comment: Are you leaving the kernel meta package installed?

Comment: Aptitude probably has them marked as automatically installed. My solution would be to try `aptitude` first, then fall back to `apt-get`.  (Why do you need Ruby for this?)

Comment: @jordanm That's a good thought, I checked into it but no I'm not, `dpkg-query -l` shows the `linux-headers` package in the same states as the specific packages.

Comment: @tripleee I suppose that's a possibility, but it seems a bit patchy & would introduce unpredictability.

Why do I need Ruby? I don't, but I like Ruby & it was faster than writing it in shell. Also, try listing your boot directory, copying one of the kernel numbers, then typing `dpkg-query -W *[paste kernel number]*`, then typing `apt-get purge [copy and paste in each of the 3 different kernel package names]`. Now do all of that 15 more times for each other kernel you want to remove. Now do that on ~70 host machines that have been running Ubuntu for ~5 years and built up a lot of kernels. :)

Comment: @jordanm Also, `dpkg-query -l` does show the `linux-headers-generic` package as installed, but it's version matches my current kernel like it's supposed to.

Comment: @damick - try `aptitude why linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic`.

Comment: @jordanm This is kinda funny:  
`Unable to find a reason to install linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.`

Answer (score 3):

`aptitude` has it's own package state database `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`, which unfortunately seems to be rather undocumented. It stores a block like this for each package:

```
Package: bash
Architecture: amd64
Unseen: no
State: 1
Dselect-State: 1
Remove-Reason: 0
```

I believe state 1 means `installed`, white state 3 means `not installed`. I also have a few packages with state 4 on my system, but I can't figure out what that means.

I believe your problem is a result of on inconsistency between the `dpkg` database `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and the `aptitude` database `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`. According to [this post](http://lists.debian.org/debian-dpkg/2012/03/msg00063.html) `pkgstates` is supposed to reflect "the user's 'intended' state for the package[s]", so aptitude probably believes that the user wants these packages to be installed even though apt-get has just removed them.

It seems like the best solution for your problem is to do what tripleee suggests: use `aptitude` if it is installed, and if not, fall back to `apt-get`.

Comment: Like you guys suggested, I will be adjusting the Rubygem to use aptitude if it's installed, apt-get if not. Thank you for this excellent clarification!